# EntityFramework. A Dependent Role has multiple principals with different values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have three classes as shown below (this is an example for my scenario) -

```
public class A
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual C c {get; set;}
}

public class B
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual C c {get; set;}
}

public class C
{
    public int AId {get; set;}
    public int BId {get; set;}

    public virtual A a {get; set;}
    public virtual B b {get; set;}
}
```

AId and BId are foreign keys from respective tables. As there is a one-to-one relationship between A and B and between A and C, I have configured the modelbuilder as -

```
modelBuilder.Entity<C>().HasRequired(p => p.A).WithRequiredDependent(k => k.C);
modelBuilder.Entity<C>().HasRequired(p => p.B).WithRequiredDependent(k => k.C);
```

Now, whenever I try to save the changes to C, I am getting an errror like -

`"Referential integrity constraint violation. A Dependent Role has multiple principals with different values."`

**Info1**: In my case, A: Id is primary key with databasegeneratedoption.identity. B: Id is a primary key with databasegeneratedoption.none.

**Info2**: I tried changing WithRequiredDependent to WithOptional, but that didn't work as well.

What can be the issue here?

### Update1

As suggested below, I removed AId, BId columns from C, but then started getting this error -

`"A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'Id'."`

What 'Id' column is mentioned above?

Comment: What is the primary key of `C`?

Comment: It's part of the model, just didn't mention here.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing properties AId and BId from C, the associations should be enough.

Comment: I tried like you said, but now there is a different error being thrown - "A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'Id'." Also, what if I want to have the AId, BId field in my table. What to do in that case?

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving the same error but for a different reason.  I had a collection of a child class (Students) that was ALSO a collection for another entity (I had two classes with Student collections).

No matter how I annotated the foreign keys, I would receive a '**Referential integrity constraint violation. A Dependent Role has multiple principals with different values' error**'.  The only solution for me was to remove the Student collection from the 2nd entity.

Answer (score 0):

You should mark foreign keys explicitly:

```
public class C
{
    [ForeignKey("A")]
    public int AId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("B")]
    public int BId {get; set;}

    public virtual A a {get; set;}
    public virtual B b {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I thought the association would take care of this. Anyways I tried this, but getting the same error.

Comment: try to inverse dependent and principal roles. modelBuilder.Entity<C>().HasRequired(p => p.A).WithRequiredPrincipal(k => k.C);
modelBuilder.Entity<C>().HasRequired(p => p.B).WithRequiredDependent(k => k.C);